# bash: partial match up to a complete word for case

Tags: bash, command, pattern-matching, dispatch

I wrote a bash script that takes a command as the first positional parameter and uses a case construct as a dispatch similar to the following:

```
do_command() {
  # responds to invocation `$0 command ...`
}

do_copy() {
  # respond to invocation: `$0 copy...`
}

do_imperative() {
  # respond to invocation: `$0 imperative ...`
}

cmd=$1
shift
case $cmd in
command)
  do_command $*
  ;;
copy)
  do_copy $*
  ;;
imperative)
  do_imperative $*
  ;;
*)
  echo "Usage: $0 [ command | copy | imperative ]" >&2
  ;;
esac
```

This script decides what function to call based on `$1` and then passes the remaining arguments to that function.  I would like to add the ability dispatch on distinct partial matches, but I want to do it in an elegant way (elegant defined as a way that is both easy to read and is not so verbose as to be an eyesore or a distraction).

The obvious functioning (but not elegant) solution might be something like this:

```
case $cmd in
command|comman|comma|comm|com)
  do_command $*
  ;;
copy|cop)
  do_copy $*
  ;;
imperative|imperativ|imperati|imperat|impera|imper|impe|imp|im|i)
  do_imperative $*
  ;;
*)
  echo "Usage: $0 [ command | copy | imperative ]" >&2
  ;;
esac
```

As you can see, explicitly enumerating all distinct permutations of each command name can get really messy.

For a moment, I thought it might be alright to use a wildcard match like this:

```
case $cmd in
com*)
  do_command $*
  ;;
cop*)
  do_copy $*
  ;;
i*)
  do_imperative $*
  ;;
*)
  echo "Usage: $0 [ command | copy | imperative ]" >&2
  ;;
esac
```

This is less of an eyesore.  However, this could result in undesirable behavior such as where `do_command` is called when `$1` is given as "comblah" or something else that shouldn't be recognized as a valid argument.

My question is:  What is the most elegant (as defined above) way to correctly dispatch such a command where the user can provide any distinct truncated form of the expected commands?

Comment: I'd say that this is rather a programming than a usability problem. My suggestion is to match exact command names such as `cp|copy)`, `command|cmd|comm)` ... instead of interpolating them. You could than add another set of matchers like e.g. `cp*|cop*)`, `command*|cm*)` after those actual command matchers and print a suggestion like "Did you mean one of the following commands: copy|cp " [...].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pattern Matching for Command Dispatch in Bash

It seems that a few of you like the idea of using a resolver to find the full command match prior to the dispatching logic.  That's might just be the best way to go for large command sets or sets that have long words.  I put together the following hacked up mess--it makes 2 passes using built-in parameter expansion substring removal.  I seems to work well enough and it keeps the dispatch logic clean of the distraction of resolving partial commands.  My bash version is 4.1.5.

```
#!/bin/bash
resolve_cmd() {
  local given=$1
  shift
  local list=($*)
  local inv=(${list[*]##${given}*})
  local OIFS=$IFS; IFS='|'; local pat="${inv[*]}"; IFS=$OIFS
  shopt -s extglob
  echo "${list[*]##+($pat)}"
  shopt -u extglob
}
valid_cmds="start stop status command copy imperative empathy emperor"

m=($(resolve_cmd $1 $valid_cmds))
if [ ${#m[*]} -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "$1 is ambiguous, possible matches: ${m[*]}" >&2
  exit 1
elif [ ${#m[*]} -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "$1 is not a recognized command." >&2
  exit 1
fi
echo "Matched command: $m"
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following solution, which should work with any
bourne-compatible shell:

```
disambiguate() {
    option="$1"
    shift
    found=""
    all=""
    comma=""
    for candidate in "$@"; do
        case "$candidate" in
            "$option"*)
                found="$candidate"
                all="$all$comma$candidate"
                comma=", "
        esac
    done    
    if [ -z "$found" ] ; then
        echo "Unknown option $option: should be one of $@" >&2
        return 1;
    fi
    if [ "$all" = "$found" ] ; then
        echo "$found"
    else
        echo "Ambigious option $option: may be $all" >&2
        return 1
    fi
}    
foo=$(disambiguate "$1" lorem ipsum dolor dollar)
if [ -z "$foo" ] ; then exit 1; fi
echo "$foo"
```

Yes, the source code of `disambiguate` is not pretty, but I hope you
won't have to look at *this* code most of the time.

Comment: That worked great right out of the box.  I would only suggest qualifying the local variables as 'local'.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update 1:

**match** is called using (partial) command as first positional parameter, followed by strings to test against. On multiple matches, each partial match will be hinted with uppercase.

```
# @pos 1 string
# @pos 2+ strings to compare against
# @ret true on one match, false on none|disambiguate match
match() {

    local w input="${1,,}" disa=();
    local len=${#input}; # needed for uppercase hints
    shift;

    for w in $*; do
        [[ "$input" == "$w" ]] && return 0;
        [[ "$w" == "$input"* ]] && disa+=($w);
    done

    if ! (( ${#disa[*]} == 1 )); then
        printf "Matches: "
        for w in ${disa[*]}; do
            printf "$( echo "${w:0:$len}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')${w:${len}} ";
        done
        echo "";
        return 1;
    fi

    return 0;
}
```

Example of usage. **match** can be tweaked to print/return the whole non disambiguate command, otherwise **do_something_with** would require some logic to resolve partial commands. (something like my first answer)

```
cmds="start stop status command copy imperative empathy emperor"

while true; do
    read -p"> " cmd
    test -z "$cmd" && exit 1;
    match $cmd $cmds && do_something_with "$cmd";
done
```

#### First answer: Case approach; would require some logic before use, to solve disambiguate partial matches.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script.sh

# set extended globbing, in most shells it's not set by default
shopt -s extglob;

do_imperative() {
    echo $*;
}

case $1 in
    i?(m?(p?(e?(r?(a?(t?(i?(v?(e))))))))))
        shift;
        do_imperative $*;
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Error: no match on $1";
        exit 1;
        ;;
esac

exit 0;
```

**i**, **im**, **imp** up till **imperative** will match. The shift will set second positional parameter as first, meaning; if the script is called as:

```
./script.sh imp say hello
```

will resolve into

```
do_imperative say hello
```

If you wish to further resolve short hand commands, use the same approach within the functions as well.

Comment: How well would this work to disambiguate many different commands? Could you expand the answer to demonstrate?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I misunderstood your question at first due to language; thinking you were after resolving partial commands in a case test (which only supports globbing). Case aren't able to match disambiguate strings and act accordingly. I'll update the post with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple (possibly even elegant) solution which will only work with bash, because it relies on the bash-specific `compgen` command.

This version assumes that the action functions are always called `do_X` where `X` is the command name. Before calling this function, you need to set `$commands` to a space-separated list of legal commands; the assumption is that legal commands will be simple words, since function names cannot include special characters.

```
doit () {
    # Do nothing if there is no command
    if (( ! $# )); then return 0; fi;
    local cmd=$1
    shift
    local -a options=($(compgen -W "$commands" "$cmd"));
    case ${#options[@]} in 
        0)
            printf "Unrecognized command '%b'\n" "$cmd" >> /dev/stderr;
            return 1
        ;;
        1)
            # Assume that the action functions all have a consistent name
            "do_$options" "$@"
        ;;
        *)
            printf "Ambigous command '%b'. Possible completions:" "$cmd";
            printf " %s" "${options[@]}";
            printf "\n";
            return 1
        ;;
    esac
}

do_command () { printf "command %s\n" "$@"; }
do_copy () { printf "copy %s\n" "$@"; }
do_imperative () { printf "imperative %s\n" "$@"; }
commands="command copy imperative"
```

Trial run:

```
$ doit cop a "b c"
copy a
copy b c
$ doit comfoo a "b c"
Unrecognized command 'comfoo'
$ doit co a "b c"
Ambigous command 'co'. Possible completions: command copy
$ doit i a "b c"
```

If you were confident that there were no stray `do_X` variables available, you could use `compgen` to make the list of commands as well:

```
command=$(compgen -Afunction do_ | cut -c4-)
```

Alternatively, you could use the same system to make a resolver, and then handle the returned option with a normal case statement:

```
# resolve cmd possible-commands
resolve () {
    # Fail silently if there is no command
    if [[ -z $1 ]]; then return 1; fi;
    local cmd=$1
    shift
    local commands="$*"
    local -a options=($(compgen -W "$commands" "$cmd"));
    case ${#options[@]} in 
        0)
            printf "Unrecognized command '%b'\n" "$cmd" >> /dev/stderr;
            return 1
        ;;
        1)
            echo $options
            return 0
        ;;
        *)
            printf "Ambigous command '%b'. Possible completions:" "$cmd";
            printf " %s" "${options[@]}";
            printf "\n";
            return 1
        ;;
    esac
}

$ resolve com command copy imperative && echo OK
command
OK
$ resolve co command copy imperative && echo OK
Ambigous command 'co'. Possible completions: command copy
$ resolve copx command copy imperative && echo OK
Unrecognized command 'copx'
```

The intent would be to write something like:

```
cmd=$(resolve "$1" "$commands") || exit 1
case "$cmd" in
  command) 
# ...
```